# Is it possible to run an Azure function on a service?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless

My website has a free "live test" tool. In order to reduce serverless costs and avoid abuse, I'd like to run it on one separate machine. If users spam the machine, it'll become slower, but it won't ruin me.

Is there a tool in Azure or AWS that would allow this? To have an Azure function 24/7 running on a low-cost server -- without any scaling and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a tool in Azure or AWS that would allow this? To have an
> Azure function 24/7 running on a low-cost server -- without any
> scaling and so on.

Yes, both providers have a pay per consumption model that you could use Azure Functions / AWS Lambda. However, you pay based on resource consumption * time spent to process each request. It means you can easily suffer [Denial of Wallet](https://owasp.org/www-pdf-archive//OWASP-Top-10-Serverless-Interpretation_(en).pdf)

As an alternative, you can spin up a very cheap Virtual Machine and route requests to it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Is there an out of the box way to run an azure function inside a VM, for production use?

Comment: You just need to host them on IIS. https://dev.to/gjcampbell/running-azure-functions-in-iis-32a